# R comparison.cloud angular position

Tags: r, word-cloud

The following code produces a simple comparison cloud:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
text1<- "cat cat dog dog dog bird bird bird bird bike bike bike"
text2<- "cat cat dog dog dog dog fish fish fish fish car car"
tmpText <- data.frame(c(text1, text2))
row.names(tmpText)<- c("text1", "text2")
ds <- DataframeSource(tmpText)
corp <- Corpus(ds)
corp <- tm_map(corp, PlainTextDocument)
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(tolower))
corp<- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
tm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp)
tm<- as.matrix(tm)
colnames(tm) <- c("text1", "text2")
comparison.cloud(tm, , scale=c(5, 1))
```

I have 2 questions:

1- If two words have the same freq in multiple documents, How the package decides to have it displayed in one sub-cloud VS the Others

2- According to documentation: "each word ... its angular position is determined by the document where that maximum occurs." I ran the comparison cloud multiple times with no seed, I could not understand the interpretation, I did Google search for explanation, did not find much, What does "Angular Position" mean within this context?

Help is greatly appreciated

MJJ

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of how `comparison.cloud` lays out the results.  Start with the term document matrix:

```
> tm
      Docs
Terms  text1 text2
  bike     3     0
  bird     4     0
  car      0     2
  cat      2     2
  dog      3     4
  fish     0     4

set.seed(19)
comparison.cloud(tm, scale=c(5, 1), random.order = FALSE, title.size = 1)
```

The plot from the above code, running set.seed(19) each time before I reran it, is below.

[image]

For font size, as the documentation explains, "The size of each word is mapped to its maximum deviation".  Hence "bird" is 4 in text1 but 0 in text2 so that is the largest "deviation" between the two texts and the largest font; "fish" is also 4-0 (but with text2 having the 4 instances so its color is different) and in the same size font, bike is 3-0, and so forth down to "cat" at no deviation being the smallest font.

As to the "angular position" of a term, the documentation explains cryptically that "its angular position is determined by the document where that maximum occurs."  The plot appears to put the largest deviation term that is alphabetically prior to a tie in the center and lays out the others by a formula that is less than clear.

Colors are determined by the text with the most instances, so that "dog" is 3 text1 and 4 text2, thus text2 brown.  Ties, such as "cat" appear to be assigned to the first text that has the term, but I haven't tested any of this interpretation.

Comment: Reading the source code from Github, the #colors=#Documents, is predetermined and fixed:
colors=brewer.pal(ncol(term.matrix),"Dark2") 
.....
text(x1,y1,words[i],cex=size[i],offset=0,srt=rotWord*90,
      col=colors[group[i]],...)
#group[i] is the doc the text belongs to

MJJDeveloper